# ASP.NET - Have my controller as custom RoutePrefix

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a controller like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class LotController : Controller
{
    [Route("{AreaLots}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string AreaLots)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is have the URL be whatever the value of AreaLots is so it looks like this localhost/MyArea instead of localhost/Lot/Index?AreaLots=MyArea

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Here is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: If you just want to remove the prefix, you can use tilde `~` in front of your RouteAttribute: `[Route(“~/MyArea”)]`. In this case `[RoutePrefix("")]` would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do localhost/MyArea but you can do localhost/Lot/MyArea (which is already better than localhost/Lot/Index?AreaLots=MyAreay) with this route config

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Lot",
    url: "Lot/{AreaLots}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Lot", action = "Index" }
);
```